# scrollbar changing the width of an image

Tags: java, image, javafx, width, scrollbar

I am going to school for programming in java. I received a program where i have to use a scrollbar to change the width of an imageView. My question is it even possible with the scrollbar API in JavaFX?

Alright Here is my code.

```
    sb = new ScrollBar();
    sb.setMax(100);
    sb.setMin(0);

    lastValue = 500;
    sb.setValue(lastValue);
    sb.setUnitIncrement(1);
    sb.blockIncrementProperty();
    sb.setOnScroll(e -> FacePart.getPart().scrollAction(lastValue));
```

this is where i am having the issue. communicating back and forth between the class that this code is in and my method that is in another class.
here is the method in the other class.

Other method

```
@Override
public void scrollAction(double j) {
    /*Global variable*/ lastScrollValue = j;
    iv.setFitWidth(300 + 2 * lastScrollValue);
}
```

Comment: Not knowing the JavaFX API, I can't help -- but it may be beneficial for you to post code illustrating what steps you've already tried and why they didn't work for you.

Comment: is that good or do you need all the code for both classes?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am very much not familiar with this sort of stuff, but the additional information will help others who are.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done, but it shouldn't be done using the `onScroll` event.

Add a [`ChangeListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/value/ChangeListener.html) to the [`value` property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollBar.html#valueProperty) instead:

```
sb.valueProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    FacePart.getPart().scrollAction(newValue.doubleValue());
});
```

Or simply use bindings:

```
iv.fitWidthProperty().bind(sb.valueProperty().multiply(2).add(300));
```

At least I guess that's what you want to do. I'm not sure why you'd use a "global" there.

Furthermore:

```
sb.blockIncrementProperty();
```

is effectively a NOP here. **If** you need to set (or get) the value, you should do it using the provided setter (or the getter):

```
sb.setBlockIncrement(someValue);
```

Doing this via the property is less readable and does the same.

Also usually you'd use a [`Slider`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Slider.html) for this (since the handle size doesn't seem to have a meaning in this case).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Fabian, just use a [Slider](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Slider.html) for this task, rather than a [ScrollBar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollBar.html).  A Slider is a more suitable control.

[image: normal]
[image: thin]
[image: fat]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.image.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class SmurfObesityMeter extends Application {
    private static final double DEFAULT_SIZE = 128;
    private static final double MIN_WIDTH = DEFAULT_SIZE / 2;
    private static final double MAX_WIDTH = DEFAULT_SIZE * 2;

    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {
        final Image image = new Image(IMAGE_LOC);
        final ImageView imageView = new ImageView(image);

        StackPane imagePane = new StackPane(imageView);
        imagePane.setMinSize(StackPane.USE_PREF_SIZE, StackPane.USE_PREF_SIZE);
        imagePane.setPrefSize(MAX_WIDTH, DEFAULT_SIZE);
        imagePane.setMaxSize(StackPane.USE_PREF_SIZE, StackPane.USE_PREF_SIZE);

        final Slider slider = new Slider(MIN_WIDTH, MAX_WIDTH, DEFAULT_SIZE);
        imageView.fitWidthProperty().bind(slider.valueProperty());

        final VBox layout = new VBox(10, imagePane, slider);
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private static final String IMAGE_LOC =
        "http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/designbolts/smurfs-movie/128/smurfette-icon.png";
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys I appreciated the help the slider works perfectly; exactly how i need it to. I'm new to Stack Overflow is there any thing i can do to give you a kudos.